# How can I link to other package's object files in OpenWRT?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, openwrt

I have a package in OpenWRT which depends on another package. My code needs to link to an object file (.o) created by the other package. What is the general way to accomplish this?

My code is in c, and compiles to an object file correctly. However, I'm failing at the linking step when creating an executable. Apologies for not being able to post Makefiles. That is not allowed by workplace policy.

Comment: There's absolutely no way we can help you given this info.  If you can't post the actual code, then create a minimal reproducible example that has the same problem as your real situation, and post that.  To give an answer with the same level of specificity as the question I would say, "to fix the problem add the object to the link command".

Comment: No need to be so hostile. I'm sorry work won't allow me to post code- you can take it up with them. I'm looking for a notional example of how this would be done., eg: package 1 creates foo.o, what is the OpenWRT way for package 2 to consume it? I could hardcode the path to foo.o in package 2, but that seems hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would use a .a or .so file for this, but it should be possible to do.
You could install the .o file in the InstallDev part of the openwrt Makefile.

```
define Build/InstallDev
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/lib/
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/foo.o $(1)/usr/lib
```

By installing it in InstallDev it is placed in the staging_dir and not installed on the device.

Then add use this file in the pakcage Makefile

```
PKG_BUILD_DEPENDS= foo-package
```